# Gradle lint now lints release builds and requires keystore password?

Tags: android, gradle, lint

I am working on a project and have recently updated to android Gradle build tools 3.0.0 (`com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0`). I am now seeing the following error when running `./gradlew lint` or the gradle lint task through Android studio:

> Execution failed for task ':app:packageDevRelease'.
>   Failed to read key alias from store "(keystore name)": Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect.

It appears that lint now requires a full release build to be signed and built, which requires the keystore password. This has never been the case in the past. Has anyone also experienced this issue or found a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a regression and a bug. It was first reported [in the Lint Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/lint-dev/OxesC-aRg6c) and the issue can be found [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62060471). Maybe this gets fixed with a `3.0.1` otherwise this might already be in `3.1.0-alpha2`.